# How to fix Sony Vegas 12.0 blank screen render?

Tags: vegas-pro, mp4

I've got video recorded from my phone and I use Vegas to edit them, when I play the video back in VLC player the video orientation is ok, but when I import into Sony Vegas and it asks if I want to set project preferences to match the media, I have

1. allowed the Vegas to match the project settings and the orientation changes to portrait.

   - when this happens I change the project settings to make the project settings to landscape and then use track motion to straigten the video. But when I render, its always a blank screen with the audio playing in the back ground.
2. not allow Vegas to match the project settings and the video shows portrait with the black strips on the side.

   - I then use track motion to straighten the video but the render produces the same result. Blank screen with audio.

I do not know why this is happening, how would I set up the import and project preferences so that the movie renders properly?

Note: All videos are mp4 format. And the media offline checkbox doesn't make a difference, checked or unchecked.

Comment: I do not know the technical reason behind it, but it seems once I import the file into the project media box, I right click the video and go to orientation and change it to 0 (original), seems to work without any error.

Comment: right click on your video and go to properties and select disable resample

Comment: Make a movie -> Save it to my hard drive -> Activate: Render loop region only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Import the file into the project media box,
2. I right click the video and go to orientation
3. change it to 0 (original)

Should render without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use VLC to get the actual frame size. You can go to Tools/media information and from there navigate through the tabs to see what the frame size is.

Then enter that information manually into vegas. When you drop your clips in everything should be good to go.

If you are still getting blank frames in the rendered video then I would guess that to be a render setting. You may want to render to a default setting to see if that helps.